# Different routes for same component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am using [React-router](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router) for routing in my reactjs web app. I want a set of different routes to render same component.

For example:

```
http://example.com/abc
http://example.com/xyz
http://example.com/pqr
```

These all URIs will render same component

Note: I dont want all routes to render same component. I just want abc , xyz and pqr to render same component

Answer (score 2):

Just define them,

```
<Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
      <Route path="abc" component={YourComponent}/>
      <Route path="xyz" component={YourComponent}/>
      <Route path="pqr" component={YourComponent}/>
      <Route path="*" component={NoMatch}/>
    </Route>
  </Router>
```

Comment: Is their any way to define this only using single line? something like  <Route path="abc|xyz|pqr" component={YourComponent}/>

Comment: I'm not sure, but if path value can be defined as regexp, you can do it.

Comment: You could have an array of paths and map through them returning a `Route` for each.